# Float format in matplotlib table

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

Given a pandas dataframe, I am trying to translate it into a table by using this code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = {"Name": ["John", "Leonardo", "Chris", "Linda"],
    "Location" : ["New York", "Florence", "Athens", "London"],
    "Age" : [41, 33, 53, 22],
    "Km": [1023,2312,1852,1345]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.axis('off')
ax.set_title("Table", fontsize=16, weight='bold')
table = ax.table(cellText=df.values,
             bbox=[0, 0, 1.5, 1],
             cellLoc='center',
             colLabels=df.columns)
```

And it works. However I can figure out how to set the format for numbers as `{:,.2f}`, that is, with commas as thousands separators and two decimals.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Insert the following two lines of code after `df` is created and the rest of your code works as desired.

The `Age` and `Km` columns are defined as type `int`; convert these to `float` before using your `str.format`:

```
df.update(df[['Age', 'Km']].astype(float))
```

Now use `DataFrame.applymap(str.format)` on these two columns:

```
df.update(df[['Age', 'Km']].applymap('{:,.2f}'.format))
```

Comment: Great! Thank you.